# Time.sleep() and win32api.Sleep() cannot work when convert .py file to .exe file

Tags: python, selenium, cx-freeze

I'm writing script using selenium webdriver with python. When i run program in IDE this script run good, But when i convert .py file to .exe and run exe file in window the delay function is not working. Maybe it passed delay function. I used both Time.sleep() and win32api.Sleep() but all of them is not display when running exe file.
Here is example:

```
import time
import win32api

time.sleep(10)
win32api.Sleep(1000)
```

Could anybody know about this? Thank you!
I'm using python 3.6, Spyder IDE. I used cx_freeze to convert py file to exe file.

Comment: Try increasing the time to a large value like `100000` and see if any of the above method works? And put a echo with date time so you know how much time it took

Comment: Thank. Now it's working but have new problem. When i copied execution folder after convert from .py file to .exe file to another computer and run execution file, It's run wrong. It's run and can't show some feature. In my system it's run well. Could you know about this? Thank you so much!

Comment: hard to say, check on cx-freeze forums